# How to call an array from model to a partial view in CHtml:encode

Tags: php, yii, view

I have three constants,

```
const STATUS_PENDING=1;
const STATUS_APPROVED=2;
const STATUS_DENY=3;
```

for them I have this method,

```
public function getLeaveStatus()
{
    return array(
        self::STATUS_APPROVED=>'Approved',
        self::STATUS_PENDING=>'Pending',
        self::STATUS_DENY=>'Denied',
    );
}
```

Now I want the **names** to be displayed in the view instead of numbers,

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($leave->status);?>
```

that displays the numbers, and on doing this,

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($leave->getLeaveStatus());?>
```

I get a

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

So how to accept an array here, or please suggest a different approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returning an array, if you want to get status name of `$leave->status` you should use this

```
public function getLeaveStatus($status)
{
   $statusNames = array(
    self::STATUS_APPROVED=>'Approved',
    self::STATUS_PENDING=>'Pending',
    self::STATUS_DENY=>'Denied',
   );

   return  $statusNames[$status];
}
```

end echo it:

```
echo CHtml::encode($leave->getLeaveStatus($leave->status));
```